# How to Enforce MyBatis PSQL custom TypeHandler on property level

Tags: java, postgresql, jersey, jax-rs, mybatis

I am using a DTO which contains `Set<UUID>` and `Set<String>`.

```
    public class MyBatisDTO implements Serializable{
    
    // other attributes
    
        private Set<UUID> uuidSet;
    
        private Set<String> stringSet;
    
      .....
}
```

A typeHandler has already been registered for Generic-Type `Set<T>`.

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.OTHER)
@MappedTypes(Set.class)
public class SetTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Set<T>> {


    @Override
    public Set<T> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return mapFromJson(rs.getString(columnName));
    }
 .......
```

Now the problem is that when above mentioned **MyBatisDTO.java** is being mapped from DB values where both columns `uuidSet` and `stringset` are stored as `jsonb` values, typeHandler picks the Generic type as String -> `T extends String` for `Set<UUID> uuidSet;` as well which is leading to auto-type conversion to all items of `uuidSet` as String. This is not an error but in debugging it can be seen that `uuidSet` contains `String` values.
Later on, which also leads in de-serialization of JAX-RS response but thats another topic which is not important at the moment. 
**My question is** Is there a way that we can enforce a typeHandler on property's level? so I am looking for a solution in which I  may attach custom TypeHandler on property level, something like this

```
//SUDO_CODE

    public class MyBatisDTO implements Serializable{
            
            // other attributes
            
                @TypeHandler ("com.mybatis.handlers.typeHandler.SetUUIDTypeHandler")
                private Set<UUID> uuidSet;
            
                @TypeHandler ("com.mybatis.handlers.typeHandler.SetStringTypeHandler")
                private Set<String> stringSet;
    .....
    }
```

OR if there is a way to mention these typeHandlers on Mapper-Level, something like this?

```
@Mapper
public interface MyBatisMapper {

 
//TYPE HANDLER ATTACHMENT/CONFIGURATION HERE ..???
    @Select("SELECT uuidSet, stringSet FROM MyBatisDTO WHERE param = #{param}")
    Cursor<MyBatisDTO> getData(@Param("param") final UUID param);
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a result map:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyBatisMapper {
    @Select("SELECT uuidSet, stringSet FROM MyBatisDTO WHERE param = #{param}")
    @Results({
      @Result(column = "uuidSet", property="uuidSet", typeHandler = "com.mybatis.handlers.typeHandler.SetUUIDTypeHandler"),
      @Result(column = "stringSet", property="stringSet", typeHandler = "com.mybatis.handlers.typeHandler.SetStringTypeHandler")
    })
    Cursor<MyBatisDTO> getData(@Param("param") final UUID param);
}
```